# Test for internet intermittency

Tags: windows, cmd

I was wondering if there is a way to write a cmd script or something for Windows that will allow me to tell when my internet connection has severed.

In Ubuntu, I would have written a shell script to ping Google once per second and if it is impossible record the time etc etc.

Is it possible to do a similar thing in Windows?

Comment: I'm not certain Google would be that impressed with your idea :-) They could probably do _without_ millions of people swamping them with ICMP packets.

Comment: Im sure they can deal with it, they have super wide bandwidth and hundreds of servers all over the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way to monitor the connection status. But here is a Windows batch implementation of the logic you specified.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set log="internetStatus.txt"
set "status="

>>%log% echo %date% %time%: Begin monitoring
for /l %%A in () do (
  >nul ping -n 2 -w 1000 google.com && (
      if "%status%"=="FAIL" (
        >>%log% echo %date% %time%: internet connection succeeded
        set "status=OK"
      )
  ) || (
      if "%status%"=="OK" (
        >>%log% echo %date% %time%: Internet connection to google.com failed
        set "status=FAIL"
      )
  )
)
```